# Connecting to MySQL database on AWS server from PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database that resides on an AWS server from within PHPMyAdmin, to be able to view its tables.

I have the connection strings (hostname, username, password), but I do not see where I would link or provide the AWS database parameters.

Ultimately what I would like to do with the tables is to use the data in my front-end userform that is created in MS Excel.

Here's what I am able to do successfully:
1. can create MySQL database (testdb)
2. can create a table (testtable) from PHPMyAdmin
3. Use the MySQL for Excel connection service to be able to connect to the testtable in the testdb and use the data in my Excel application.

The problem I am having is bringing or linking to the MySQL database on the AWS server to my testdb.  I just want to be able to see a list of the AWS database tables in Phpmyadmin.  Is that possible?

Comment: What is the OS on AWS server ? If it is ubuntu 16.04, you can [follow these steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) to setup phpmyadmin on the aws server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. You can edit config.inc.php file of phpmyadmin to add as many servers as you want

Here is the link with the guide

https://tecadmin.net/add-multiple-hosts-in-phpmyadmin/

Comment: thanks for your response.  I've searched all of my files in my web directory and can't find the config.inc.php file.   Where would this file be located?   I am using PHPMyAdmin within my GoDaddy web account.   Does PHPMyAdmin have to be installed on my personal computer that is running Windows 10?

Comment: If you are on shared hosting then you cannot change the configuration for PHPMyAdmin. And Yes, you can install it on your local machine or put phpmyadmin on your server webroot path to access your own phpmyadmin instance. Also by default you will find config.sample.inc.php at the root level of phpmyadmin folder. You need to rename to config.inc.php